# How to reposition the legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, legend

Right now, it looks like this:

[image]

I don't like that the box intersects the function graph. How could you reposition it?

And I cannot see the label for the y-axis. Where has it gone? Could you also make the y-axis a little bit longer, so you can see the arrow of the y-axis completely?

The code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$}
]

\addplot [
    domain=-20:20, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{sin(deg(x)) / deg(x)};
\addlegendentry{$si(x) = sin(x) / x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: nit: `$\operatorname{si}(x) = \sin(x) / x$`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    ymax=1.2,
    legend style={at={(0.65,.9)},anchor=north west},
]
\addplot [
    domain=-20:20,
    samples=200,
    color=blue,
]
{sin(deg(x)) / (x)};
\addlegendentry{$si(x) = sin(x) / x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `si(x)` function should have a maximum of `1`, so the function should read `{sin(deg(x)) / (x)}` instead of `{sin(deg(x)) / deg(x)}`. Also to enlarge the y-axis a bit we can add `ymax=1.2,`. For positioning the legend, we can adjust the position by the legend style `legend style={at={(0.65,.9)},anchor=north west}`.

Answer (score 7):

you can utilize `xshift` and `yshift` to position the legend. (I've used @Harish Kumar's answer though but I solved the problem with `shifts`).

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    enlarge y limits=upper,
    yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
    xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
    legend style={xshift=1.5cm},
    thick,
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot 
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    domain=-20:20,
    samples=200,
    color=blue,
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{sin(deg(x)) / (x)};
\addlegendentry{$si(x) = sin(x) / x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `legend style` to reposition the legend.

```
legend style={at={(0.65,1)},anchor=north west},
```

Here the coordinate `(0,0)` corresponds to lower left corner and `(1,1)` corresponds to upper right corner. The `ylabel` is hidden under the legend and once you move the legend it becomes visible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
    ytick=1,
    legend style={at={(0.65,1)},anchor=north west},
    enlarge y limits=upper,  %% or enlargelimits=upper (if you want x axis too)

]

\addplot [
    domain=-20:20,
    samples=100,
    color=blue,
]
{sin(deg(x)) / (x)};
\addlegendentry{$si(x) = sin(x) / x$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer, I will accept it, but I edited my question with one more point. Could you also make the y-axis a little bit longer so you can see the arrow of the y-axis completly?

Comment: @Joey: Sure. Please see the edit using `enlarge y limits`